# createMemoryHistory still reports `Browser history needs a DOM`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am receiving the error which for all purposes I believe I should not be :)

The flow is

**Client** `history.js` > `client/index.js` > `history = createBrowserHistory` > `<App history={history} />`

**Server** `history.js` > `server/index.js` > `history = createMemoryHistory` > `<App history={history} />`

I can confirm that Memory is being used on the server, which it then falls down so we never get to the `BroswerHistory`

**Error in server.js**

```
Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM

  30 | 
  31 |          // Render the component to a string
> 32 |          const markup = renderToString(
  33 |              <Provider store={store}>
  34 |                  <App history={history} />
  35 |              </Provider>
```

## history.js

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import createMemoryHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory'

let history
let createHistory

if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
    createHistory = createBrowserHistory
} else {
    createHistory = createMemoryHistory
}
history = createHistory()

export default history
```

I have checked and made sure that the `<BrowserRouter />` is not the wrong place either.

## routes.js

```
const routes = (
    <Fragment>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Fragment>
)

export default routes
```

## server.js

```
 import history from '../common/history'

 const store = configureStore(preloadedState, history)

// Render the component to a string
const markup = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App history={history} />
    </Provider>
)
```

## App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import routes from '../routes'

const App = ({ history }) => {
    return <ConnectedRouter history={history}>{routes}</ConnectedRouter>
}

App.propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object
}

export default App
```

Comment: Where are you using the exported `history` object? Shouldn't you use that with `Router` instead of using `BrowserRouter`? `<Router history={history}> ... </Router>`

Comment: exported `history` is used in multiple places, `server/index.js`, `client/index.js` and then passed as props down to `App.js` through both of these `server/client` files

Comment: Alright. Consider changing `<BrowserRouter>` to `<Router history={history} />` instead and see if that works.

Comment: Did you see this question? Maybe the root cause is similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649569/browser-history-needs-a-dom?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @Jacob but yes indeed, I have already made sure that I am passing `createMemoryHistory`

Comment: @Tholle I am using `connected-react-router v5`, just as a note. Indeed this worked :D please add the answer and a brief explanation about why if possible :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BrowserRouter` component creates a `history` object of its own, and it's always the [HTML5 history API](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) which will not work in a non-DOM environment e.g. the server.

You could structure your app to not include the `BrowserRouter` on the server, or you could replace it with the [`Router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) component and pass it your own `history` object that will use the memory history in non-DOM environments.

```
const routes = (
    <Fragment>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Fragment>
)
```

Comment: Thanks pal, I didn't realise it makes it own `history`, great to know.